# Указать падеж существительного, одушевленность, род

Tags: падежи, род, одушевленность

> Испугался ужа (*кого?*) сестрЫ.

Родительный падеж?

Answer (score 2):

***Испугался ужа*** (Р.п.) ***сестры*** (Р.п.).

*Сестры* ― ж.р., одуш.,  Р.п.

Это Р.п. со значением принадлежности, выбор падежа в слове  ***сестры*** (женский род) не зависит от одушевленности, это всегда Р.п.

*Ужа* ― м.р., одуш,. Р.п.

Глагол ***испугаться*** (ужа, грома, грозы) также управляет только  Р.п. существительных (одушевленных и неодушевленных).